# Java PUT Request Zotero 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, put

I am trying to send PUT request to the Zotero API, but I keep getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: ['itemType' property not provided]
```

The JSON being sent is fine, so it is something with my code.

```
private void handleUpdateItemButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Properties props = restConnection.getAccessProperties();
        ResponseEntity<JsonNode> res = restConnection.getRestTemplate().exchange(this.getItem(props, itemKey), new ParameterizedTypeReference<JsonNode>() {
        });

        if (res.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            JsonNode jsonNode = res.getBody();
            printJSON(jsonNode);
            JSONObject jsonObject = convertNodetoObject(jsonNode);
            JSONObject jsonData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            //jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").put("title", "This is the new title");
            jsonData.put("title", "This is the new title");

            ResponseEntity<JsonNode> updatedItem = restConnection.getRestTemplate().exchange(this.updateItem(props, jsonData, itemKey), new ParameterizedTypeReference<JsonNode>() {
            });

        }

        else{
            System.out.println("This item cannot be updated");
        }
    }
```

The method above then calls the method below

```
private RequestEntity updateItem(Properties props, JSONObject item, String itemKey) throws JsonProcessingException {
            ResponseEntity<JsonNode> res = restConnection.getRestTemplate().exchange(this.getItem(props, itemKey), new ParameterizedTypeReference<JsonNode>() {
            });        
        return RequestEntity
                .put(restConnection.getZoteroBaseURL() + "/users/" + props.getProperty("username") + "/items/" + itemKey)
                .header("Zotero-API-Version", "3")
                .header("Zotero-API-Key", props.getProperty("key"))
                .header("If-Unmodified-Since-Version", numberBody.get("version").toString())
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(item);
        }
```

Not really sure what is wrong. I'd appreciate any help - zoter-dev said that the PUT request should work and it's something with my code. Thanks!

Comment: "*`... ['itemType' property not provided]` ...*"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a good look at the [Zotero Web API documentation](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/web_api/v3/basics).

If you examine the [creating an item](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/web_api/v3/write_requests#creating_an_item) section you'll find what you need to pass in your API call in order for it to work:

```
[
  {
    "itemType" : "book",
    "title" : "My Book",
    "creators" : [
      {
        "creatorType":"author",
        "firstName" : "Sam",
        "lastName" : "McAuthor"
      },
      {
        "creatorType":"editor",
        "name" : "John T. Singlefield"
      }
    ],
    "tags" : [
      { "tag" : "awesome" },
      { "tag" : "rad", "type" : 1 }
    ],
    "collections" : [
      "BCDE3456", "CDEF4567"
    ],
    "relations" : {
      "owl:sameAs" : "http://zotero.org/groups/1/items/JKLM6543",
      "dc:relation" : "http://zotero.org/groups/1/items/PQRS6789",
      "dc:replaces" : "http://zotero.org/users/1/items/BCDE5432"
    }
  }
]
```

It's stated that `All properties other than itemType, tags, collections, and relations are optional`, meaning `itemType` is mandatory.
You must fill in these four properties, at least, if you want your call to succeed.

If you don't have any data for `tags`, `collections` or `relations` you could just pass empty property values:

```
{
  "itemType" : "note",
  "note" : "My sample note",
  "tags" : [],
  "collections" : [],
  "relations" : {}
}
```